# What does "Book skin" mean in this context? (I've got extra book skin from breastfeeding)

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, informal-language

"I've got extra book skin from breastfeeding"

What does "book skin" exactly mean here?

Comment: Did you hear this? If you did, I suspect that you misheard the word *book*, as it was most likely *boob*, a term for *breast*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Nah, it's written, you can have a look on it.
 [imgur](https://imgur.com/W0BojEU)

Comment: Uhm, that link is NSFW.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Yeah, I just got it from YouTube directly. Anyhow, I just typed the sentence that appeared in the video as it's written, 'Book'. That's it.

Comment: You are adding lots of context to the question in the comments. Consider putting all this context into the question. You need to provide the link to the source from the start! Now Which Youtube video is it from?

Comment: @JamesK [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5eH3bqp0iU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5eH3bqp0iU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an expression she made up for "skin with fine wrinkles, so it looks like pages from a book".  Not a standard expression, but the meaning is obvious from the video.  She shows you wrinkled skin and says it is "book skin" - so now you know what "book skin" is, it is that thing that she shows you.